# Displaying tags associated with posts in Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called 'camps', which has tags associated with it, registered as 'camps_tag'

I have managed to list all of the posts from a certain category within the 'camps' cpt, but how can I list the tags associated with the post?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) or its big brother [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms). It's how you display custom taxonomies on the front end -- similar to `the_category` or `the_tags`.

Example:

```
<?php
// somewhere in a template file, inside the loop
the_terms(
    $post->ID, // object ID
    'camps_tag', // your custom taxonomy
    '<p><strong>Tags: </strong></p>', // before the list
    ', ', // between list items
    '</p>' // after the list
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if I was supposed to be looking at tags or taxonomy documentation. Will give that a go